How to use `.menuOrder(.priority)` inside a `List`
Is .menuOrder(.priority) not working inside a List? It works as it should without the List. Inside one it doesn't work.
Is there any other way to switch the order or make the contextMenu appear at the bottom?
List {
    Color.gray
        .frame(height: 400)
    Text("Numbers")
        .padding()
        .contextMenu {
            Button("1", action: { })
            Button("2", action: { })
            Button("3", action: { })
            Button("4", action: { })
        }
        .menuOrder(.priority)
}


I think this is likely a bug.
A workaround is to use contextMenu(forSelectionType:menu:primaryAction:) on the List. This means that the List must be selectable, which may not be desirable.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var x: Int?
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $x) {
            Color.gray
                .frame(height: 400)
            Text("Numbers")
                .padding()
                .tag(1)
        }
        .contextMenu(forSelectionType: Int.self) { selection in
            if selection.contains(1) {
                Button("1", action: { })
                Button("2", action: { })
                Button("3", action: { })
                Button("4", action: { })
            }
        }
        .menuOrder(.priority)
        .onChange(of: x) {
            x = nil
        }
    }
}

